# Using automatic screen brightness with ThinkPad X260

Tags: 18.04, screen, brightness, thinkpad

I'd like to use automatic screen brightness with my X260 under Ubuntu 18.04. In Windows 10 it worked properly, but with Ubuntu the sensor is not found or I don't know - I'm not able to set automatic screen brightness under settings.

Could you guys help me please - thanks a lot.

Comment: https://certification.ubuntu.com/make/Lenovo?query=&category=Desktop&category=Laptop&category=Server&category=Server%20SoC&category=Ubuntu%20Core&level=&release=18.04%20LTS&page=2 shows it's not certified for Ubuntu 18.04. Doesn't mean it worn't work, just that there's no easy answer from Canonical.

Comment: X260 is certified for 16.04 so I think the driver for the brightness sensor would work on Ubuntu 18.04, but how do I activate the driver?